# Can't add controller with scaffold c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When I try to add new controller with scaffold visual studio prompt a error message:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
> Unable to resolve service for type
> 1Microsoft.EntityFramework.DbContextOptions1

[image: Attempt to add controller]

[image: Error Message]

I have already check other question about the same problem but the answer didn't applied to my case cause already is a reference in my DbContext class to **DbContext**

```
public class HospitalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public HospitalDbContext(DbContextOptions<HospitalDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And Program.cs is

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var conf = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddDbContext<HospitalDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    conf.GetConnectionString("Default")
    )
);

var app = builder.Build();
```

This is the project link on github under branch "stackoverflow": https://github.com/heitorgiacominibrasil/Hospital-Management-System-ASPNETCORE/tree/stackoverflow

Comment: Project link is broken

Comment: @FortyTwo https://github.com/heitorgiacominibrasil/Hospital-Management-System-ASPNETCORE/tree/stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Solved by creating a new asp.net core mvc project, added an folder with the models/classes I needed, added the dbcontext and generated the scaffold process again. After the scaffold finished I coppied the controllers and views to my original project. This problem seems to happens when are multiple projects, and scaffold can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

I have had something similar happend once. I am not sure if this will apply to this issue but when I had this error, I just kept on pressing the "Add" button. After a couple of tries it just added the controller.

Not really sure if it will fix it but everytime I do this it works.